# Run "mysql" command from bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, docker, mariadb

I have a MariaDB Docker container that I want to access automatically with the help of a bash script.

I'm using Docker compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  drupal:
    image: jonasvbogaert/php-docker:${IMAGE_VERSION}
    container_name: drupalenv
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/
    restart: always
    environment:
      DRUPAL_SITE_NAME: Drupal
      DRUPAL_USER: admin
      DRUPAL_PASS: admin
  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:latest
    container_name: mariadbenv
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3036:3036
    depends_on:
      - drupal
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
      MYSQL_USER: drupal
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: drupal
      MYSQL_DATABASE: drupal`
```

The first command is to dive in the container (works fine):

```
docker exec -it mariadbenv bash
```

But the second one:

```
mysql
```

outputs the following error:

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'jonasvb'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
the input device is not a TTY`

When I enter "mysql" myself, it works.

This is the script I use:

```
function main () {
  getUserInput
}


function fireDocker () {
  if [ $DRUPAL_VERSION = "7" ]; then                            
    IMAGE_VERSION="drupal7"                                     
    export IMAGE_VERSION                                        
    docker-compose up -d                                         
    mountDump
  else
    IMAGE_VERSION="drupal8"                                     
    export IMAGE_VERSION                                        
    docker-compose up -d                                        
    mountDump
  fi
}

function getUserInput () {
  echo "Enter Drupal version (7 or 8)"
  read DRUPAL_VERSION                                           # Read 
  fireDocker $DRUPAL_VERSION
}

function mountDump(){
  docker exec -it mariadbenv bash
  mysql

}


main
```

EDIT

When I execute the first command without -t flag.
I have this: [image]

And it stays like this.

Comment: remove the `t`.

Comment: Removed the "t", but now it keeps executing (no output).

Comment: what about executing `bash -c mysql`

Comment: What do you want to do with the mysql command exactly? You need to manually do something or you want to automate some execution?

Comment: Same result as @123 answer.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I want to automate the import of SQL dumps for a migration process.

Comment: Are you using `docker-compose` or just `docker`? Also post you batch file or `docker-compose.yml` whichever you are using

Comment: Looks like your user does not exist in the docker environment. 
Try `mysql -u root`
That's for the first error.
`mysql -u root -e 'select CURTIME()'` should return the current date.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis If I do it manually, it works fine.

Comment: @JonasVanBogaert what do you mean with `manually`? Can you provide the entire bash script?

Comment: If you just want to import the database you can as well place the sql script inside container at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`

Comment: @Ayushya, that's true but I want to automate things. looping over a folder with all the dumps.

Comment: instead of `docker exec it...`
try using this:
`docker exec -i mariadbenv mysql -u drupal -p drupal  <<< "select database();"`

Comment: Have you tried: `mysql -u $DB_USER -p$DB_PASS $DB_NAME -e "SHOW TABLES"`? With mysql in cli if you specify -p it tells mysql to use password auth instead of unix socket if enabled, please not that if you do not want to enter the password you need to pass the password in the command without as space, i.e. mysql -u root -ppassword1 my_database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run mysql commands in container using

```
docker exec -i some_mysql_container mysql --user=root --password=root  <<< "select database();"
```

Here the password and username should match with the one that is being used in the container.

A better approach in your cases would be to place all the dumps in the host and then map that host directory inside container at `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. For a better understanding how all dumps are imported in container you may look at official [`entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/e841926a0c09fb1d1d7dd79131f9d8e3a09619ec/10.2/docker-entrypoint.sh#L170) of mariadb:latest

L170 onwards:

```
    for f in /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*; do
        case "$f" in
            *.sh)     echo "$0: running $f"; . "$f" ;;
            *.sql)    echo "$0: running $f"; "${mysql[@]}" < "$f"; echo ;;
            *.sql.gz) echo "$0: running $f"; gunzip -c "$f" | "${mysql[@]}"; echo ;;
            *)        echo "$0: ignoring $f" ;;
        esac
        echo
    done
```

This enables users to place everything inside `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` and then

- run bash scripts from there
- run sql scripts
- restore archived databases